# import JavaScript module in angular nx project

Tags: javascript, angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have an angular project built with [nx](https://nx.dev/angular) I want to import standard JavaScript libraries which do not have typescript typings for example I want to install and use [cytoscape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cytoscape) and  [cytoscape-context-menus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cytoscape-context-menus)

I get compilation errors such as

> error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'cytoscape-context-menus'.
> 'C:/dev/armo/armo-ng-app/node_modules/cytoscape-context-menus/cytoscape-context-menus.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cytoscape-context-menus` if it exists or add a new declaration
> (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cytoscape-context-menus';`

How can I solve them? I tried to put declaration files but I think my setup doesn't see them.

Answer (score 1):

since there's no available type definition npm package, you have to write your own. start with the ones you need and continue to build on top of it as needed.

if you like you can share it too as an npm package.

found this article for writing TypeScript type definition files by @dubtypescript: http://blog.wolksoftware.com/contributing-to-definitelytyped

also take a look at how cytoscope is typed from here, borrow their ways: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cytoscape/index.d.ts

Added a stackblitz to checkout:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-6cyuem?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcytoscape-context-menus.d.ts

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work. Some don't have typings in "DefinitelyTyped". Also I try addeding .d.ts file but still I get compilation erros

Comment: @canbax added a stackblitz to check out

Comment: thank you for your efforts but for me the important thing is the `tsconfig.json` file. Stackblitz doesn't have that file. Also, I can't use `@types/cytoscape`. It breaks many things in my application because I don't use type definitions for many things

Comment: should be able to download the stackblitz project and check tsconfigs. although it should still work with standard angular app. you may also manually type cytoscope in similar manner.

Comment: I'm still getting the error. The problem is with architecture of nx project. I don't really understand how can I add the typings.

Comment: i think it is not about nx. anyway you could always create/start a simple app and try out.

for the stackblitz app provided. i just added a file 

`cytoscape-context-menus.d.ts` and add my declaration there, maybe put the file along the component.ts, ts will generally see it

Comment: I just solved my issue. Inside "tsconfig.base.json" file I should set the compiler option ""noImplicitAny": false,"

Comment: not quite right but if your happy that is all that matters. 
try to read more about ts too

Comment: "Not quite right" Is it setting "noImplicitAny" to false? Do I have any option if I'm going to use JS libraries without types?

Comment: well, seems it is okay in your case your trading type safety for progress